# RxSwift pagination

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

I can't manage to get this solution to work: 
https://github.com/liuznsn/RxMoyaPaginationNetworking

Maybe someone can tell me where is the mistake. The loading variable never goes to false. I guess the issue is in the request observable, but I can't find out why.

```
class PaginationNetworkModel<T1: Mappable>: NSObject {

let refreshTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
let loadNextPageTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
let loading = Variable<Bool>(false)
let elements = Variable<[T1]>([])
var offset:Int = 0
let error = PublishSubject<Swift.Error>()

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override init() {
    super.init()

    let refreshRequest = loading.asObservable()
        .sample(refreshTrigger)
        .flatMap { [unowned self] loading -> Observable<[T1]> in
            if loading {
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                return self.loadData(offset: self.offset)
            }
    }

    let nextPageRequest = loading.asObservable()
        .sample(loadNextPageTrigger)
        .flatMap { [unowned self] loading -> Observable<[T1]> in
            if loading {
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                self.offset += 1
                return self.loadData(offset: self.offset)
            }
    }

    let request = Observable
        .of(refreshRequest, nextPageRequest)
        .merge()
        .shareReplay(1)

    let response = request.flatMap { events -> Observable<[T1]> in
        request
            .do(onError: { error in
                self.error.onNext(error)
            }).catchError({ error -> Observable<[T1]> in
                Observable.empty()
            })
    }.shareReplay(1)

    Observable
        .combineLatest(request, response, elements.asObservable()) { [unowned self] request, response, elements in
            return self.offset == 0 ? response : elements + response
        }
        .sample(response)
        .bind(to: elements)
        .addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)

    Observable
        .of(request.map { _ in true },
            response.map { $0.count == 0 },
            error.map { _ in false }
        )
        .merge()
        .bind(to: loading)
        .addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)
}

func loadData(offset: Int) -> Observable<[T1]> {
    return Observable.empty()
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that your `loadData` function never returns any data which means `response` never fires?

Comment: Yeah. As you could see it generic class, and if I need other server method I inherit this class. I'm sure response fires, i.e. if I set request.map to false I will get all objects from server, but without "loading" feature.

Comment: For some reason request.map called after response.map, where sets false, and immediately sets to true coz of request, but I can't see where it get called after response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    let refreshRequest: Observable<[T1]> = loading.asObservable()
        .sample(refreshTrigger)
        .flatMap { [unowned self] loading -> Observable<[T1]> in
            if loading {
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                return self.loadData(offset: self.offset)
            }
    }
```

refreshRequest doesn't emit a value until *after* loadData returns. The way your code is structured, emitting a signal on the `refreshTrigger` will start the network request, and then set loading to true after the network request completes.

It would be better to have `refreshRequest` and `nextPageRequest` return an Observable of what page to load and then merge them and call `flatMap` with the network call on the merged result.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you Daniel for help, here completed solution

Call example:

```
goodsModel = GoodsNetworkModel()
    goodsModel.elements.asObservable().bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: StoreCell.self)) { (ip, item: Goods, cell: StoreCell) in
        cell.configure(goods: item)
    }.addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)

    tableView.rx.itemSelected.bind() { [unowned self] ip in
        self.didSelectRow(ip: ip.row)
    }.addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)

    rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewDidAppear(_:)))
        .map { _ in () }
        .bind(to: goodsModel.refreshTrigger)
        .addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)

    tableView.rx_reachedBottom
        .map{ _ in ()}
        .bind(to: goodsModel.loadNextPageTrigger)
        .addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)
```

Model code:

```
class PaginationNetworkModel<T1: Mappable>: NSObject {

let refreshTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
let loadNextPageTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
let loading = Variable<Bool>(false)
let elements = Variable<[T1]>([])
var offset:Int = 0
let error = PublishSubject<Swift.Error>()

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override init() {
    super.init()

    let refreshRequest = loading.asObservable()
        .sample(refreshTrigger)
        .flatMap { loading -> Observable<Int> in
            if loading {
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                return Observable<Int>.create { observer in
                    observer.onNext(0)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                    return Disposables.create()
                }
            }
    }

    let nextPageRequest = loading.asObservable()
        .sample(loadNextPageTrigger)
        .flatMap { [unowned self] loading -> Observable<Int> in
            if loading {
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                return Observable<Int>.create { [unowned self] observer in
                    self.offset += 1
                    observer.onNext(self.offset)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                    return Disposables.create()
                }
            }
    }

    let request = Observable
        .of(refreshRequest, nextPageRequest)
        .merge()
        .shareReplay(1)

    let response = request.flatMap { offset -> Observable<[T1]> in
        self.loadData(offset: offset)
            .do(onError: { [weak self] error in
                self?.error.onNext(error)
            }).catchError({ error -> Observable<[T1]> in
                Observable.empty()
            })
        }.shareReplay(1)

    Observable
        .combineLatest(request, response, elements.asObservable()) { [unowned self] request, response, elements in
            return self.offset == 0 ? response : elements + response
        }
        .sample(response)
        .bind(to: elements)
        .addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)

    Observable
        .of(request.map{_ in true},
            response.map { $0.count == 0 },
            error.map { _ in false })
        .merge()
        .bind(to: loading)
        .addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)
}

func loadData(offset: Int) -> Observable<[T1]> {
    return Observable.empty()
}
```

Comment: If I create a `PaginationNetworkModel` then trigger its `loadNextPageTrigger`, the model will attempt to load page 1 without ever attempting to load page 0. Are you sure this is correct behavior?

Comment: Edit my answer, so there before calling loadNextPageTrigger I always call refreshTrigger